# How to repeat the page-contents on the same page

Tags: paper-size, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple copies of short page on one sheet of paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13781/multiple-copies-of-short-page-on-one-sheet-of-paper)

I am a school teacher. I have the following need. I have to distribute a large number of quizzes to about 200 students each week. Each quiz text is very short; just a small header which is followed by 3/4 lines of text.

So I want to repeat the entire quiz contents verbatim (including the header/footer, if any), on the same A4 size page. This way I can print 4 to 5 pamphlets on a A4 size paper and then cut them to distribute (to save paper and thus trees).

I saw the `leaflet` class and its documentation, but am not sure whether this can be achieved with leaflet class. Also the labels package doesn't seem right for this.

Given below is the TeX code for a sample quiz that I am trying out.

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\runningheadrule%remove comment for horizontal line at top of every page.
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5ex}{0ex}
\newcommand{\attempt}[1]{Attempt any \textbf{#1} of the following.}
\pointsinrightmargin \extraheadheight[.7in]{0pt}
\firstpageheader{\textbf{Time: 20 min}}%left
                {\textbf{\large Name of the institute}\\
                \textbf{Subtitle if any\\
                 Quiz/Test - 1  
                  }
                }%centre
                {\textbf{Date:\hspace{10 mm} Marks:}}%right
\runningheader{\ifcontinuation{\textbf{Q. \ContinuedQuestion. Continued\ldots}\hrule}
                                { }}%left
              { }%centre
              { }%right
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\hspace{-10pt}\textbf{Q.\thequestion.}}
%remove above Comm to print Ques lable
\footer{ }%\oddeven{}{\iflastpage{}{\textbf{[P.T.O.]}}}}%left
             {\iflastpage{}{}}%centre
         {\iflastpage{}{\textbf{[P.T.O.]}}}%right
\pointformat{\textbf{[\themarginpoints]}}%print points in brackets.
\raggedbottom
\linespread{0.7}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question

Write the square of each of the following in front of it:\\
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 25\hspace{14 mm}
\choice 36\hspace{14 mm}
\choice 9\hspace{14 mm}
\choice 49\hspace{14 mm}
\end{oneparchoices}

\question
Expand ${(3x+4y+7z)^2}$(Write answer on the back of the sheet, if needed.)

\end{questions}

%DOCUMENT_FOOTER
\begin{center} \line(1,0){450} \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436) I'm confident that other question will solve your problem, have a look. That's why I voted to close this question as a duplicate – just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If you need more help, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you. (Also, we don't usually put a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.)

Comment: @doncherry: thanks. yes, I'd like to close my question. How do I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can close your own question with the low amount of reputation points you have. There might be a "close" link between "edit" and "flag", above the comments and below your questions. If it's not there, don't worry. There'll be enough high-rep users coming by this question and casting their vote. Thanks for being responsive and open to being closed! `:)`

Comment: @KkDd: It is ok to have duplicate questions as that should make it easier for others to find. Once the question is closed it will have a link to the duplicate question.  I have seen others delete their question, but I think it is better to _not_ delete it and have it closed as a duplicate.  You don't need to do anything, it will get closed once a few more people come along.