# Printing Two Double-Sided Copies of an A5 Document on A4 Paper

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

I'm using LaTeX to write a quiz for the calculus class that I'm teaching, and I'm trying to save paper by using both sides of half a sheet of A4 paper (i.e., an A5 sheet) instead of one side of an A4 sheet.  I'd like to print two double-sided copies of the quiz on a single sheet of A4 paper - i.e., the front side of the A4 sheet contains two copies of page 1, and the back side contains two copies of page 2.  Is there a simple way to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Other answers can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36558/printing-a-double-sided-a5-document-on-a4-paper?rq=1)

Comment: @LoopSpace Okay, I withdraw my vote.

Comment: See also [Printing a double-sided A5 document on A4 paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36558/printing-a-double-sided-a5-document-on-a4-paper)

Comment: @LoopSpace it's done now :-)

Comment: @LoopSpace Will you also offer the `tikzmark` library to Tikz developers?

Comment: @AndréC My feeling is that tikzmark (which is already on ctan) and pgfmorepages have different relationships to the core pgf code.  Tikzmark builds something extra, but pgfmorepages replaces (and extends) something existing. If pgf doesn't want it, I'll happily upload it to ctan.

Answer (score 6):

This may be achieved by using `pgfpages` package that provides `\pgfpageuselayout` command to be put in the preambule of the document.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've written an extension of `pgfpages` imaginatively called `pgfmorepages` ([CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages) and [github](https://github.com/loopspace/pgfmorepages)) which can handle repeating pages.  The following code has two pages and each is repeated.  Printing them out will give you two A5 double-sided copies.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452197/86}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfmorepagesloadextralayouts

\pgfpagesuselayout{repeated 2-up}[a4paper]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The resulting pages look like this:

[image: first page]

[image: second page]

If downloading from github, you need both `pgfmorepages.sty` and `pgfmorepageslayouts.code.tex`.

Comment: Oh! I'd use the repeated layout. Will you put this on CTAN?

Comment: @DavidPurton I've just been bug-fixing with a view to making it more readily available (it is downloadable from github) but thought I should offer it to the pgf maintainers first.

Comment: @DavidPurton It's now on CTAN.