# Printing half-page worksheets without copy/pasting the entire text?

Tags: printing

I write daily half-page worksheets for my class.  At the end of the document I `\newpage` and copy the entire text so I can print the document 2-sided short-edge binding and then cut the paper in half to get two worksheets per sheet of paper.  I do it this way instead of putting the text right under the other copy so I can use the header on both pages.  If I need a whole page of stuff, I just make sure there is enough of a space in the middle that I can cut between the lines and the bottom half of one page ends up on the backside of the top half of the other page.  This has been working just fine, but it can be a bit of a pain to edit the file.  Is there some command I can put in the preamble to make it automatically print a second page that is identical to the first page?

Comment: This _sounds_ like the sort of thing that `pgfmorepages` was designed for.  In particular, the `repeated 2-up` layout.  See https://github.com/loopspace/pgfmorepages

Comment: Excellent! '''\usepackage[landscape]{geometry} \usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfmorepagesloadextralayouts
\pgfpagesuselayout{repeated 2-up}''' works nicely!  I need to tweak the margins a bit, but this should be good. Thank you!

Comment: I quite often use `scale=.85` via the geometry package for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of using `pgfmorepages` to achieve this (as seen at [Printing Two Double-Sided Copies of an A5 Document on A4 Paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452197/86), though I've added the `landscape` option here which might be needed due to a change in some package or other):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452197/86}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfmorepagesloadextralayouts

\pgfpagesuselayout{repeated 2-up}[a4paper,landscape]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```